# Static declarations and definitions inside of function scope don't change?

Tags: c++, static, macros

Ok, on assigning a static variable declared in a constructor/function (I don't think it matters which) to a compile time defined value, it's as if the variables only been assigned once, see Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define y  4
#define z  3
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x)
    {
        static int i = x;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo p(y);
    Foo o(z);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

4

3

Actual output:

4

4

I couldn't find anything on searching, though if this is a dupe just let me know and i'll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static` local variable is initialized only once when the function it resides in is entered for the first time. So only the first initialization happens, and all further ones are ignored.

Here's your program, modified to illustrate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#define y  4
#define z  3
using namespace std;

struct Bar {
    int i;
    Bar(int i) : i{i}
    {
        cout << "Bar::Bar with " << i << '\n';
    } 
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x)
    {
        static Bar b = x;
        cout << b.i << '\n';
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo p(y);
    Foo o(z);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want each subsequent call to modify `i`, you need to *assign* into it:

```
static int i; // default initialize i.
i = x; // assign a new value into i
```